# Reverse characters in alphabet

Tags: bash, terminal

How can I reverse

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

so that it would be something like

```
"ZYXW..."
```

I know it's a fairly basic question, but the help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, from what you have said, I would say just finish typing it. However I as sure this is not what you mean. May be see command `tr`. But I can't give any more advice until I know what you are trying to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why wouldn't `echo "ZYXW..."` be acceptable? Please [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: @roaima Why would they need to edit their question? All is well: they asked a simple question, they got the correct simple answer, now they can proceed with whatever they're doing. It's not our business. If they actually wanted tips on how to translate their general idea into code, they'd have done that.

Comment: 1/2 @kangalioo there are different ways to achieve the question that's been asked. The most trivial one is `echo "ZYX...BCA"`. Another might be to pipe into `tr '[A-Z]' 'ZYX...CBA'`. (And actually that's a really bad solution because could easily break, depending on the locale.) And so on. With more context it may be possible to offer a better solution.

Comment: 2/2 @kangalioo Secondly, on this Stack people are encouraged to post what they have already tried, even though it doesn't work.Often, explaining why an attempt does not work - and therefore what does work instead - is really helpful to the person asking the question. Not only do they get an answer, they have hopefully learned something too.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to explain the question's intent by asking: **What output is desired if the input is (say) "HELLO"?**  (Both "OLLEH" and "SVOOL" seem good matches for the question as it currently stands, though there are several other possibilities.)

Comment: Okay I'm just gonna play the representative of common sense then. @roaima Is it not obvious that "ZYXW..." is just an example? Obviously OP does _not_ need bash just to print the alphabet in reverse. He's very capable of doing that without help from his computer. Common sense tells us that the original question is equal to: "Given an arbitrary unknown input string of arbitrary length, output the given string in reverse order". And come on now, that is not so hard. Just pipe it into rev, and that's your answer right there. No need to theorize on the OP's intention, just answer the damn question

Comment: @gidds I don't see how SVOOL could possibly be a good match, I really can't. Isn't OLLEH the only sensible answer here?

Comment: @kangalioo I think you've just illustrated the ambiguity of this question!  If it were only about reversing the characters in a _string_ — which would give OLLEH — why mention the alphabet?  My original interpretation was that it was about _transliterating_ characters by reversing the alphabet: exchanging As for Zs, Bs for Ys, and so on.  Which would give SVOOL in this example.

Comment: @gidds What you're doing is _transliterating_. What was asked is _reversing_.

Comment: @kangalioo Yes: reversing the characters in the alphabet, and then using that to transliterate a string.  Can you not see that as a _possible_ interpretation of the question?  (At least one other commenter before me interpreted it that way, hence the mention of `tr`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107755/discussion-between-kangalioo-and-gidds).

Answer (score 10):

The `rev` command will reverse strings:

```
echo ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | rev
```

produces output

```
ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to print a reversed string.

```
echo -n "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" | tac -rs '\w'
```

will produce:

```
ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

Comment: `echo 'ABC DEF' | tac -rs '\w'` produces `FE DCBA` with a newline before and none after, rather than `FED CBA` here. Too difficult for me to guess this shifted space, but I'm not sure that's what OP would want.

Comment: This will place the newline at the start of the string.

Comment: My comment was not an answer to your comment, it just happens that my comment came after yours. You comment is spot on, no issue from me. @A.B

Comment: `echo -n "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" | tac -rs '\w'` will get rid of the newline. Thanks, I'm correcting the solution above.

Comment: If you replaced `| tac -rs '\w'` with `| tac -rs '.'` this would fix the space issue.

Comment: And because separator is a regexp, you can do funny things like:
`echo -n "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" | tac -rs '\w\w'`
That will produce: `YZWXUVSTQROPMNKLIJGHEFCDAB`